# Android applications with differnt package names are not able to install in same device.

Tags: android, apk

I created two apk files with package name com.example.a and com.example.a.staging. But I am not able to install the both on the same device together. It will install separately.While try to install one after installed the other, it shows an error 'app not installed'

Comment: change `application id` in `gradle` and try

Comment: show how you defined different packages

Comment: Check if you have enabled "workspace" and if app is installed in workspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have faced similar situations.

possible scenarios:

1.*you didn't change `applicationId` in app/gradle*.

**Solution:** In that case, change `applicationId`.

2.you have a defined a provider for facebook(or something similar) in AndroidManifest.xml like `android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXXX`.

**Solution:** Comment out that provider for testing or add different ids for providers for different build variants.

Answer (score 1):

first, you change package name in your manifest file, then you paste the changed package name to your build.gradle(app level) on applicationId place